# Matrix RERSful API with Laravel and Guzzle. Request creating

Tags: laravel, api, matrix, guzzle

I am newbie in PHP and have quite pure experience working with RESTful API. So if anyone can help with my problem I will very appreciate it.

The goal is to create a chat room in Matrix, make some basic steps as registration, logging in and further communication between couple of clients over that room.

**Problem 1:**
It looks like this is the only one documentation that is available at internet at all.
https://matrix.org/docs/guides/client-server.html

And it is not clear for me.  Could not find any other good examples of what I need.

**Problem 2:** 
No sure what type of request to use, as I understand RESTful API can use many of them: Simple request, Asynchronous request, Conccurent request, and the syntax of course differs.

**Problem 3:** 
Not sure if I correctly make an request them selves. Examples below.

**What I have already done:** 
Because my project in on Laravel, I use Guzzle client to form my queries and via composer have already installet Matrix dependancy as its described here:
https://github.com/updivision/matrix-php-sdk

Here is example of my request, which of course don't work properly:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;


    $client = new Client();


$promise = $client->requestAsync(
    'POST',
    'http://matrix.loc:80/_matrix/client/r0/register',
    [
        'json'=>[
            'username'=>'12345',
            'password'=>'12345',
            'auth'=>[
                "type"=>"m.login.dummy"
            ],
        ]
    ]
);


  $promise->then(
    function(Response $resp){
        echo $resp->getBody();
    },
    function(RequestExcprion $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK wraps all the API calls so you don't need to be creating requests through Guzzle. Instead look through the [resources directory](https://github.com/updivision/matrix-php-sdk/tree/master/src/Resources) and understand what the SDK offers. Lets start with a registration request, it is available [here](https://github.com/updivision/matrix-php-sdk/blob/6ce47ffee72e6300c54e473e9d20b174846beb26/src/Resources/UserData.php#L207) in the source.

**register.blade.php**

Start by creating a simple registration form.

```
<form action="{{ route('maxtrix.register') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

**routes/matrix.php**

Create a routes file for matrix api requests. This is optional, you can just put these in your existing `routes/api.php` file, but I prefer keeping things separated.

```
Route::post('register', 'MatrixController@register')->name('matrix.register');
Route::get('account', 'MatrixController@account')->name('matrix.account');
```

**MatrixController.php**

Create a new controller to make the matrix api requests.

```
class MatrixController {

    protected $userData;

    // Use dependency injection to automatically get an instance of the 
    // matrix SDK.
    public function __construct(UserData $userData)
    {
         $this->userData = $userData;
    }

    // The registration form created above will post to this route which
    // will make the API request to register your user.
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // get the data from the response
        $data = $this->userData->register($request->username, $request->password);

        // if successful, save the registration info
        if ($data) {
             DB::table('matrix_regisration')->insert($data);
             return redirect()->route('matrix.account');
        } else {
        // if failure, redirect back to the registration for with errors
             return back()->withErrors('Failed to register');
        }
    }
}
```

I simplified a few things, but that should get you started in the right direction. I looked through the SDK and it appears to have everything pretty well documented as far as creating rooms, starting chat sessions, inviting other users, etc.

Have fun!